# How to translate language in yii

Tags: yii, language-translation

In my Yii web application, I want to translate the language for entire application. Is this possible in Yii? How to do this easily. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Yii1 you can read official documentation with examples - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n

For Yii2 you can read by this link - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html